# JPA Error : Transaction is currently active

Tags: java, spring, jpa

When I run my unit tests in isolation they work fine ie. (omitted the asserts)

```
@Test
public void testSave()
 {
EntityManagerHelper emh = new EntityManagerHelper();
LevelDAO dao = new LevelDAO();
Level l = new Level();
l.setName("aname");
emh.beginTransaction();
dao.save(l);
emh.commit();
}
```

then running this individual test below no problem

```
@Test
public void testUpdate()
 {
EntityManagerHelper emh = new EntityManagerHelper();
LevelDAO dao = new LevelDAO();
Level l = new Level();
l.setName("bname");
l.setLevelid(1);
emh.beginTransaction();
dao.update(l);
emh.commit();
}
```

When they run at same time in sequence I recieve that error - **Transaction is currently active**. Is there a way to allow each unit test to run only after a transaction from previous piece of work is not active? Should I be looking at Spring instead?

**Update**

The EntityManagerHelper gains access to the persistence context like so

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bw_beta");        
threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
```

which looks like the problem

So a hacky workaround was to use define locally ie.

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bw_beta");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    dao.save(l);
    entityManager.persist(l);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Pretty sure there's a better way - maybe using Spring?

Comment: What happens inside `EntityManagerHelper`?

Comment: @DataNucleus: he doesn't say that he wants to run them in parallel.

Comment: And what's the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Pretty sure there's a better way - maybe using Spring?*

Yes, Spring cleans it up a lot and gives you control on what you'd like to run within a transaction without polluting the actual test.

With Spring, your tests would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/application-context.xml",
                        "classpath:META-INF/conf/spring/test-datasource-spring-config.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=false)
public class LevelDaoTest {

    @Resource( name="levelDao" )
    LevelDao levelDao;

    @Test
    public void shouldSaveNewLevels() {

        Level l = new Level();
        l.setName("aname");
        levelDao.save(l);
        // assert
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUpdateExistingLevels() {

        Level l = new Level(); // or I would assume, you'd read this level back from DB, or set a proper ID, so the DAO will know to update it.. But that is besides the point
        l.setName("bname");
        levelDao.update(l);
        // assert
    }
}
```

Take a look at Spring Documentation under [Testing => Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testing-tx) to get more details.

*P.S. From your example:*

```
dao.save(l);
entityManager.persist(l);
```

*Looks really strange, as usually you would encapsulate `entityManager` within a DAO, so all you'd need to do is `dao.save(l)`*

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may be having this issue here is how I resolved it.  I was doing multiple saves and I kept getting this error.  You do not want to begin multiple transactions without checking if it is active.

```
if(!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive())
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
dao.save(l);
entityManager.persist(l);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I implemented a Singleton approach to handle it.